# set timers / wait for nothing

Tags: java, selenium, appium

My scenario is that from my app I open the waze wait 25sec, go to home screen, wait 10sec, than the system move back to waze, than I wait 15sec than again going to home page and wait there 10sec,

```java
mainScreen.openWaze();
TimeWatch watch = TimeWatch.start();
double passedTimeInSeconds = 0;
System.out.println("start");
while (passedTimeInSeconds < 26.0) {
    passedTimeInSeconds = watch.time(TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    System.out.println("the seconds of 1 " + passedTimeInSeconds);
    wazeInApp.validateWhereToField();
}
watch.reset();
passedTimeInSeconds = 0;
wazeInApp.goToHomeScreen();
while (passedTimeInSeconds < 11.0) {
    passedTimeInSeconds = watch.time(TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    System.out.println("the seconds of 2 " + passedTimeInSeconds);
    wazeInApp.validateWhereToField();
}
watch.reset();
passedTimeInSeconds = 0;
while (passedTimeInSeconds < 16.0) {
    passedTimeInSeconds = watch.time(TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    System.out.println("the seconds 3 " + passedTimeInSeconds);
    wazeInApp.validateWhereToField();
}
wazeInApp.goToHomeScreen();
```

my console prints :

```
start
the seconds of 1 0.0
the seconds of 1 12.0
the seconds of 1 13.0
the seconds of 1 13.0
the seconds of 1 34.0
the seconds of 2 0.0
the seconds of 2 0.0
the seconds of 2 0.0
the seconds of 2 0.0
the seconds of 2 9.0
the seconds of 2 15.0
the seconds 3 0.0
the seconds 3 2.0
the seconds 3 4.0
the seconds 3 6.0
the seconds 3 9.0
the seconds 3 11.0
the seconds 3 13.0
the seconds 3 34.0
```

it looks strange that the prints are not at the correct time, also it beyond the time limits , and also does these is the right solution for just wait (for nothing)?
Thank you

Comment: What are you trying to do? Halt the execution for particular time period?

Comment: yes but I don't want to do Thread.sleep

Comment: Debug your code to see variable values during runtime.

Comment: @pburgr did that and it is the printed stack as you see

Comment: does these is the right solution for just wait (for nothing)? --> can you post the code of openWaze() and validateWhereToField()? If we can see that then only we can tell you. 

can you try int passedTimeInSeconds = 0;?

Comment: the openWaze and the validation is just steps in my app and they are not related to the stop of the runing, the passedTimeInSeconds return  long:

```public class TimeWatch {
    long starts;

    public static TimeWatch start() {
        return new TimeWatch();}
    public TimeWatch reset() {
        starts = System.currentTimeMillis();
        return this;}
    public long time() {
        long ends = System.currentTimeMillis();
        return ends - starts;}
    public long time(TimeUnit unit) {
        return unit.convert(time(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);}
}```

Comment: @ness posted an answer. Please try and let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are trying to check for something in this 26 seconds times so you are not preferring `Thread.sleep()` I tried the below way and it worked for me.  Here I am taking system current second and adding 26 to it(our expected time) so the loop will iterate till 26 seconds from current second.

```
long passedTimeInSeconds = 0, earlierSecond = 0, currentSecond = 0;
long waitTillTime =  Instant.now().getEpochSecond() +26;
while(passedTimeInSeconds < waitTillTime){
    passedTimeInSeconds = Instant.now().getEpochSecond();
    earlierSecond = passedTimeInSeconds%60+1;
    currentSecond = Instant.now().getEpochSecond()% 60 + 1;
    if(currentSecond > earlierSecond) {
    System.out.println("Second: "+earlierSecond);
    }
```

**Output**:

```
Second: 37
Second: 38
Second: 41
Second: 43
Second: 44
Second: 45
Second: 46
Second: 47
Second: 49
Second: 51
Second: 52
Second: 54
Second: 58
Second: 59
Second: 1
```

Due to milliseconds sometimes condition may fail.

Comment: it's looks Ok but the thing is that just printing it once - doesn't it suppose to print each iteration under the while? second, it prints the time as 1627384470 and I want to see it in seconds..how to convert it from 1970?

Comment: @ness now it prints the current second of the minute. Please try and let me know. It is little tough to print only when the second changes because if we added condition and it should compare between old and new time before printing statement once but due to milliseconds the condition may fail sometimes. I added code for that also.